# javascript global variable undefined when calling inside the new, additional function

Tags: javascript, arrays

Coding linting with JS to iterate through a text.
I have a few iterations that count a specific conditions, for example
sentences
are set to be added upon when there is '.' or '!'.

However, when I created a function that would print one string with information about number of sentences, overused words and so on, it shows up as undefined... Here's a piece of code

```
console.log(betterWords.length);
let counter = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < betterWords.length; i++){
  if (betterWords[i] === 'really' || betterWords[i] === 'very' || betterWords[i] === 'basically'){
    counter++
}
}
console.log('You used overused words ' + counter + ' times.');

let sentences = 0;

betterWords.forEach (word => {
  if (word[word.length-1] === '.' || word[word.length-1] === '!'){
    sentences++
}
});

console.log('There are ' + sentences + ' sentences');
numberOfWords = betterWords.length;

const printFunction = (betterWords, counter, sentences) => {
  return('The number of words in text is ' + numberOfWords + ' There are ' + sentences + ' and overused words are used ' + counter + ' times.');
};

console.log(printFunction());
```

Output
182
You used overused words 8 times.
There are 12 sentences
The number of words in text is 182 There are undefined and overused words are used undefined times. I am mentioning sentences as one example here. One can see that numberOfWords give a proper output

As one can see once sentences return 12, the other time it's undefined.

Comment: Scope in JS. `printFunction` takes three parameters `betterWords`, `counter`, and `sentences` but you call it with none: `console.log(printFunction())` so these are `undefined`. `numberOfWords` is not a parameter and JS will pick the variable from the outer scope.

Comment: The `sencences` and `counter` parameters to your `printFunction` are hiding the global values. But as you don't provide a value for them, when you call the function, they are `undefined`